# jQuery validation number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single input field where the user can only enter a number between 2 AND 50. Anything above or below is invalid. It also MUST be a numeric value.

What I have so far is this:

```
$('#searchTimes').click(function() {
if($('#replyNumber').val()<=0) {
        alert("Please select a value greater than 0 for number of guests");
    $('#replyNumber').focus();
        return;
    } 

    if($('#replyNumber').val()>=51) {
        alert("Please select a value less than or equal to 50 for number of guests");
    $('#replyNumber').focus();
        return;
    }

    if(isNaN($('#replyNumber').val())) {
       alert("Please enter a numeric value only");
       $('#replyNumber').focus();
       return;
    }    
});
```

Is there a better more efficient way of writing that ^.

Also ... IF all of those IF statements are not true then I need to perform another function. How can I add that in?

Comment: Your last condition will never run, since `val()` always returns a string, never NaN. You probably want to `parseInt($('#replyNumber').val(), 10)` before checking the value. If this code works as is, this question might be better asked on [codereview.se], but check their help center first.

Comment: First of all take the value once, try to parse it to int and store in a variable - no need to invoke .val() method in every if statement. Then, to have a block of code execute if all other conditions are false, you should make an is...else chain instead of three separate if's, and put a simple else at the end which will be executed only if all other conditions are not met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_isValidNumber(number) {
 var message;
 var isValid;
 switch(number){      
   case number >= 51:
     message = "Please select a value less than or equal to 50 for number of guests";
     isValid = false;

   case number <= 0:
     message = "Please select a value greater than 0 for number of guests";
     isValid = false;

   case isNumeric(number):
     var message = "Please enter a numeric value only";
     isValid = false;

   default:
     return true;
  }
  alert(message);
  $('#replyNumber').focus()
  return isValid;
}

function isNumeric(num){
   return !isNaN(num)
}

var number = $('#replyNumber').val();
var numberIsValid = _isValidNumber(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to abstract out duplicate code, like this:

```
<input id="replyNumber" >

<button id="searchTimes">click</button>

<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#searchTimes').click(function() {
    var val = $('#replyNumber').val()


    if(val<=0) showErr("Please select a value greater than 0 for number of guests");    
    else if(val>=51) showErr("Please select a value less than or equal to 50 for number of guests");
    else if(isNaN(val))showErr("Please enter a numeric value only");

});


function showErr(msg){
       alert(msg);
       $('#replyNumber').focus();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## This is what you need :D

```
$('#searchTimes').on('click',function() {
    var do_function = 1;
    if (!$.isNumeric($('#replyNumber').val())) {
        alert("Please enter a numeric value only");
        $('#replyNumber').focus().select();
    } else if (+$('#replyNumber').val() < 2) {
        alert("Please select a value at least 2 for number of guests");
        $('#replyNumber').focus().select();
    } else if (+$('#replyNumber').val() > 50) {
        alert("Please select a value no more than 50 for number of guests");
        $('#replyNumber').focus().select();
    } else {
        do_function = 0;
    }
    if (do_function) {
        call_some_function();
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 `min` and `max` attributes and an `input` of type `number` (which covers the numeric part you mentioned). Use `rangeOverflow` and `rangeUnderflow` Validity Properties to check your input and present the proper error (or custom error) messages.

Try the below snippet using the following values (null (empty input),1,55) and check the custom error messages created.

```js
function validateInput() {
    var txt = "";
    if (document.getElementById("inp1").validity.rangeOverflow) {
       txt = "Value larger than acceptable!";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("inp1").validity.rangeUnderflow) {
       txt = "Value smaller than acceptable";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("inp1").validity.valueMissing) {
       txt = "Please type a number!";
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = txt;
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
validateInput();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="inp1" name="numberInput" min="2" max="50" required>
  <button id="btn">go</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```